# Why is curl unable to use a password protected key?

Tags: c, ssl, curl, https, libcurl

Curl SSL connection fails when I have a password on the client key

I am trying to make a https POST request, with the client authenticating itself with the remote system with an appropriate certificate and private key

In the following code, if 'pathToAuthKey' refers to a non-password-protected key, it all works fine. No errors. No warnings. The connection is established and all is good.

If 'pathToAuthKey' refers to the **SAME** key but password protected, and I provide the password via the 'authKeyPwd' string, I get the following response from Curl;-

```
* About to connect() to 10.10.4.71 port 443 (#1)
*   Trying 10.10.4.71...
* Connected to 10.10.4.71 (10.10.4.71) port 443 (#1)
* unable to load client key: -8178 (SEC_ERROR_BAD_KEY)
* NSS error -8178 (SEC_ERROR_BAD_KEY)
* Peer's public key is invalid.
* Closing connection 1
```

Essentially, Curl seems to be either ignoring the password I give it, or it is unable to decrypt the key with the specified password, for reasons unknown. The password string I am giving Curl is just that; just the raw password, so "abcde", and not something like "pass:abcde" (though I have tried all sorts of combinations)

I get the same error response if I use the command line (though I'm not sure I am specifying the password correctly here);-

```
curl -k -v --cert ./.ssh/authCert.pem --key --pass abcde ./.ssh/authKey.pem https://10.10.4.71/
```

...or (?)...

```
curl -k -v --cert ./.ssh/authCert.pem --key ./.ssh/authKey.pem:abcde https://10.10.4.71/
```

The key and certificate are in PEM format. I read somewhere that they should include the "bag" information to work with Curl. I have tried with and without - it makes no difference. I have also tried many variations of the following code (doing stuff in a different order, trying other options, etc), but no luck

I started with a key PEM format with `----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----` headers, but read somewhere that Curl doesn't like this so changed it to `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`. I have tried the key PEM file with and without the `Proc-Type` and `DEK-Info` info (though I can't see how SSL would decode the key without this info, unless it just tries all combinations until it succeeds), ie -

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,FD47E79520E2C2A1E3B5D9B769C713A9

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX .......etc.....
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I have tried combining the key with the certificate file.

The certificate is self-signed (though I can't see how this could effect the (lack of) password success)

One final thing - I have seen the `CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD` option called `CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD`. I have tried both, Curl seems to accept both, but I don't know if there is a difference (the official docs don't mention the latter form)

This is on a Centos 6 machine. Curl version...

```
curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.36 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.4.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz unix-sockets
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated

This is the C code I have;-

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl"); // Identify ourselves

// Set up timeout handler
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION, curlTimeoutCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_XFERINFODATA, &transferStartTime);

// Set up the response handler
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curlResponseCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);

// Create HTTP request data
char postData[MAX_JSON_POST_LEN] = {"My POST data"};
int postLen = strlen(postData);

// Construct URL to send request to
char url[] = {"https://10.10.4.71/"};
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L); // ###

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, "PEM");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, pathToAuthCert);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE, "PEM");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, pathToAuthKey);

if (*authKeyPwd)
{
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD, authKeyPwd);
}

// Try and simplify things for now by disabling verification of the remote system
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);

// Send request
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &transferStartTime);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, postLen);

CURLcode curlResp = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Comment: try to use `curl -k -v --cert ./.ssh/authCert.pem --key ./.ssh/authKey.pem --pass abcde https://10.10.4.71/` <- this should be the correct syntax

Comment: For the C source: start by trying to set the authKeyPwd to a string literal like `"abcde"` to rule out errors on reading in the passphrase

Comment: curl -k -v --cert ./.ssh/authCert.pem --key ./.ssh/authKey.pem --pass abcde https://10.10.4.71/ - Same result - "SEC_ERROR_BAD_KEY"

Comment: I tried a literal for the key - no luck

Comment: Something I should have mentioned - the key without the password has been extracted from the key WITH the password, so I know the password/key encryption isn't at fault

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the `--pass` argument. Correct form is:
`curl --cert /path/to/cert:password --key /path/to/key https://example.com`

It's also documented here:
https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/tls/clientcert